# JQuery slider navigation behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a perfectly good working slider but I need to alter the behavior slightly as in the way the navigation works.

On the first slide I wish to have only the right/next option available and 2nd/3rd/4th etc to have both left and right or next and previous available. Once you reach the end slide the next or right option is hidden so it does not loop round.

Here is my script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

on moveLeft and moveRight functions you could check $('#slider ul').attr("left") attribute. If it's 0 you are on first slide if it's equal to ($('#slider ul').attr("width") - ($('#slider ul li').attr("width"))) you are on the last.

Comment: Sorry I do not seem to understand, could you take a take that section and paste to me where the attr would go?

Answer (score 0):

```
function moveLeft() {
    if($('#slider ul').position().left > 0){
     $('#slider ul').animate({
         left: + slideWidth
     }, 200, function () {
         $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
         $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
     });
    }
};
function moveRight() {
    if($('#slider ul').position().left < (sliderUlWidth - slideWidth)){
     $('#slider ul').animate({
         left: + slideWidth
     }, 200, function () {
         $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
         $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
     });
    }
};
```

Comment: i didn't see $('#slider ul').css('left', ''); and prepend line.

Comment: why didn't you leave that slides and left in their place and only animate the ul positioning?

Comment: I just used left/previous and right/next to understand what I am trying to achieve. The buttons are simply just navigation buttons. I tried the code suggested and it did change the behavior but muddled it all up.